# How can I fix this error with my API (404 not found)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rest

I'm making an application that takes codes from mongoDB and lists them onto a web page, but currently I'm getting an error in the console:

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/code/codes/ 404 (Not Found) zone.js:2863

I haven't encountered this error before & I'm not sure if there is an error in my code or a problem with a port, my server starts on port 3000 and angular portion starts up on port 4200. here is my api to find all codes

```
router.get("/codes", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    Code.find({}, function (err, codes) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(501).send({
          message: `MongoDB Exception: ${err}`,
        });
      } else {
        console.log(codes);
        res.json(codes);
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: `Server Exception: ${e.message}`,
    });
  }
});
```

my service file

```
export class CodeService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  findAllCodes() {
    return this.http.get('api/code/codes/');
  }

}
```

and my home component ts where I'm trying to display the codes

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  code: Code[];

  constructor(private codeService: CodeService) {
    this.codeService.findAllCodes().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        // Logging for debugging purposes
        console.log('--Server respons from findAllCodes--');
        console.log(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('--Server error--');
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => {

        console.log('--codes--');
        console.log(this.code);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If it's a front-end request (front end running on 4200) to the back end (back end running on 3000) then you need to include the port in the request. Also not clear if the route is nested, e.g., you show it mapped as a GET to `/codes` but make the request to `/code/codes`.

Comment: 404 means the path you’re requesting wasn’t found. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404 - so `/api/code/codes` (As shown in the error message) isn’t a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the API as you did, you will make the request to the same source of your web application, so when you call this route, instead of calling your API route, you are calling a route of your own web app.

To fix that, you need to check in which port your API is running and do one of the following:

1. Create a [proxy file](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) that will redirect your API calls to the port that you are using. Example:

**In your root dir: proxy.json**

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

2. Do the calls with the full path for the API:

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:[SERVER_PORT]/api/code/codes/');
```

If you don't have CORS configuration on your server, you might need to configure it, because you are going to make a call to your API from a different domain. If you are using node.js with express check this [link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).